# Scraping table using html_table in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table, html-parsing, rvest

I want to scrape the Sector Weightings Table from the following link:

http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/summary?t=SPY&region=usa&culture=en-US&ownerCountry=USA

The table i want is table 6 in the website's source code. I have the following script written in R:

```
 library(rvest)
 turl = 'http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/summary?t=SPY'
 turlr = read_html(turl) 
 df6<-html_table(html_nodes(turlr, 'table')[[6]], fill = TRUE)
```

However when i run the last line of the script i get the following error message

> Error in out[j + k, ] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: You should see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Precisely you didn't include the important code that had produced this error

Comment: There are embedded charts and groupings in your target table. You will need to alter the returned node before it will be accepted by `html_table`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730647/scraping-html-table-with-span-using-rvest) question for some guidance.

Comment: There are nigh countless R + scraping + morningstar posts on SO. Which ones did not have info that could have helped you? I'm constantly mystified abt this since it take more energy to create a q than to do an actual search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the required table is designed in a different way `rvest` is not able to format it into proper table. But using `XML` package you can do it quite easily.

```
library(XML)
library(dplyr)

#read required table
turl = 'http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/summary?t=SPY'
temp_table <- readHTMLTable(turl)[[6]]

#process table to readable format
final_table <- temp_table %>%
  select(V2, V3, V4, V5) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  `colnames<-` (c("","% Stocks","Benchmark","Category Avg")) %>%
  `rownames<-` (seq_len(nrow(.)))
final_table
```

Output is:

```
                          % Stocks Benchmark Category Avg
1                Cyclical                                
2         Basic Materials     2.79      3.16         3.22
3       Consumer Cyclical    11.06     11.42        11.15
4      Financial Services    16.39     16.50        17.22
5             Real Estate     2.24      3.18         2.00
6               Sensitive                                
7  Communication Services     3.56      3.37         3.50
8                  Energy     5.83      5.79         5.79
9             Industrials    10.37     10.89        11.70
10             Technology    22.16     21.41        19.72
11              Defensive                                
12     Consumer Defensive     8.20      7.60         8.56
13             Healthcare    14.24     13.57        14.57
14              Utilities     3.15      3.11         2.59
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot!